# How to implement aggregate in erlang MongoDB driver

Tags: mongodb, erlang

I am trying to use aggregate with the [erlang mongodb driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-erlang). This is what I have tried so far

```
mongo_query:command({Db, Conn}, {aggregate,<<"users">>,pipeline, <<"{$group:{_id:\"\", id: {$sum: \"$id\"}} }, {$project:{ _id:0, id: \"$id\"}}">>}, false).
```

but I recieve this error

```
** exception error: {bad_command,{errmsg,<<"exception: wrong type for field (pipeline) 2 != 4">>,
                                         code,13111,ok,0.0}}
```

I am having trouble moving forward and am looking for any help with a way to implement aggregate with the erlang driver.

Just to be clear I am trying to implement this

> db.users.aggregate({$group:{_id:"", id: {$sum: "$id"}} },
>   {$project:{ _id:0, id: "$id"}});

which works in the MongoDB shell.

Answer (score 1):

I would defer to someone who knows erlang if one had chimed in yet, but since no one has: I think you are supplying a string for the pipeline argument where the driver is expecting a list.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:
`mongo:command(Connection, {aggregate,<<"users">>,pipeline, [{'$group',{'_id', id, {'$sum', '$id'}}}, {'$project',{'_id',0, id, '$id'}}]}).`